# How to avoid calling a method with soql inside loop?

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I am writing a batch class in which **I am calling my custom-defined method inside for loop. But the main problem is my custom-defined method executes a soql** query which means it's a bad idea to call it inside the loop. How can I avoid it?

Here is my code please have a look. I've commented on code for your better understanding

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<staging__c> scope){
    for(staging__c sc:scope){
        if(sc != null && sc.Individual_or_organization__c  == 'I') {
            // calling this custom method inside loop
            Account objAccount = searchAccount(sc);
    }
    }
}
// method that executes soql to match account and return it to my batch class
private Account searchAccount(staging__c scope) {
        Account acc= new Account();
        if(scope.Orgganization_Name__c != null && scope.Postal_Code__c != null) {
            system.debug('acc not zero');
            // want to avoid this soql inside loop
            acc= [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :scope.Orgganization_Name__c AND BillingPostalCode = :scope.Postal_Code__c];
        }
        return acc;
    }
```

Comment: I would have answered your previous version of this, but you deleted it. In general, you just need to do the [Aggregate-Query-Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern.

Comment: @sfdcfox Hi, I would never delete that question but some folks just things it duplicates even though it's not. Unfortunately, I have to delete it but never wanted to.

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please help me I couldn't understand how aggregate queries can help? I am new to salesforce just started learning it :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming combination of `Postal_Code__c` and `Organization_Name__c` returns only one account from org.

You can do something like this:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Staging__c> scope){
    Set<String> uniquePostalCode = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> uniqueOrganizationName = new Set<String>();
    for(Staging__c sc:scope){
        if(sc != null && sc.Individual_or_organization__c  == 'I') {
            // calling this custom method inside loop
            uniquePostalCode.add(scope.Postal_Code__c);
            uniqueOrganizationName.add(scope.Organization_Name__c);
        }
    }
    uniquePostalCode.remove(null);
    uniqueOrganizationName.remove(null);

    if(!uniquePostalCode.isEmpty() && !uniqueOrganizationName.isEmpty()) {
        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingPostalCode FROM Account WHERE Name IN :uniqueOrganizationName AND BillingPostalCode IN :uniquePostalCode LIMIT 50000];
        Map<String, Account> accountMapByNameAndBillingPostalCode = new Map<String, Account>();

        for (Account account : accounts) {
            accountMapByNameAndBillingPostalCode.put(account.Name + account.BillingPostalCode, account);
        }

        for (Staging__c sc : scope) {
            Account account = accountMapByNameAndBillingPostalCode.get(sc.Postal_Code__c + sc.Organization_Name__c);
            //account found
        }
    }
}
```

Fetch all `Postal_Code__c` and `Organization_Name__c` in a `Set` and the fire a query on Account.

And create a `Map` combining Name and BillingPostalCode from Account, again assuming only one record exists with this combination, orelse you can change this.

then finally loop again on your scope variable and fetch account from the map as shown above.